# Using Webrtc for streaming video from client to server

Tags: c++, streaming, webrtc, rtp

I want to use webrtc for getting users' webcam/camera data to my server. I always see implementations of Webrtc for peer-to-peer connections. However is it possible to just use Webrtc for sending information to a server over rtp(using c++ native api of webrtc eh?)?

I was trying to wrap my head around this situation but could not find a clear tutorial or start point for this task.,

Some link to a tutorial or code piece will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There really are no native tutorials for WebRTC development. You could take a look at [Erizo](https://github.com/ging/licode/tree/master/erizo) for a simpler C++/C library for WebRTC.

Comment: There is an example called [call] in the webrtc native framework. That can be your starting point on webcam video sharing. Its not a baked cake to get it working. You  might need to do some work around for that and starting asking question on forums as you get struck.

Comment: thanks for the starting points. i think i will need to dig deep for this